# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'putVocabularies' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm currently developing an app. I'm new to aws-amplify everything was working completely fine until my baby sister deleted my node modules by mistake. After reinstalling my node modules I get these two errors

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'putVocabularies' of undefined, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

if im correct i know main can come up if the wrong dependencies are installed.

Please i was very close to completing my project and this have me at a major set back

I tried reinstalling aws-amplify install as well as aws-amplify-react-native but nothing works I get the same error over and over

UPDATE
This is package.json

{
"name": "mapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@aws-amplify/interactions": "^6.0.26",
"@aws-amplify/react-native": "^1.0.27",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.0",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
"@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
"@react-native/metro-babel-transformer": "^0.73.15",
"@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.5",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
"aws-amplify": "^6.0.26",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.8",
"axios": "^1.6.7",
"expo": "^50.0.6",
"expo-barcode-scanner": "^12.9.3",
"expo-camera": "^14.0.6",
"expo-contacts": "~12.8.2",
"expo-image-picker": "^14.7.1",
"expo-location": "~16.5.3",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
"graphql": "^16.6.0",
"metro-runtime": "^0.80.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.73.6",
"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-maps": "1.10.0",
"react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
"react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
"react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"metro-config": "^0.80.6",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0"
},
"private": true
}

Comment: Hi @lannel-hamilton, I think your question could be better tagged with react-native. Your first error message indicates, that putVocabularies() is being called, but not defined. Maybe it's about https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/utilities/i18n/#putvocabularies and you are missing the import of `import { I18n } from 'aws-amplify/utils'` either in your code or in your package.json / dependencies. So maybe you need to share more informations, code or the content of your package.json to get better answers. Good luck and happy coding!